# Sync-up updates from SDL Tridion 2013 into 2009

Tags: 2013, 2009

I have a requirement for pushing content updates from 2013 to 2009 on a scheduled basis. I was thinking of using the Core Service to connect and update but 2009 doesn't support it.

Also content porting is an option but the export package should be compatible to import in 2009 which requires additional effort. Please suggest if there are other approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WebDAV functionality or TOM API to add and change content in SDL Tridion 2009.

Comment: I thought of getting the webdav urls for the updated components using core service in 2013 and then use this webdav url to find and update contents in 2009, but core service will not work in 2009.

Comment: Extract new content from 2013 with core service in xml form. Then use some other application/function to add the changes to Tridion 2009.